# EditText inside ConstraintLayout not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-edittext, android-constraintlayout

I have an `AppCompatEditText` as a search bar and a `FrameLayout` as a "Clear" button, both inside a `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ...
    android:layoutDirection="ltr">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/clearBtnLyt"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        ...
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/editText1">

        ... CONTENTS ...

    </FrameLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/clearBtnLyt"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar1" />

    ...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The `ConstraintLayout` is set to be left-to-right and only the `AppCompatEditText` is RTL. These views have shown well in the Android Studio's Layout Preview.

[image]

But when I ran the app on my Samsung Galaxy A5 (2017) with Android 8.0 OS, it looked like this:

[image]

I can't type anything in the `AppCompatEditText` or click it, but the "Clear" button is working. My phone is also set to be left-to-right. *What am I doing wrong?*

Comment: xml would require here

Comment: @pankaj-kumar I also wrote the `ConstraintLayout` code. Please review it.

Comment: why don't you put the layout_width of the AppCompatEditText to "match_parent"?

Comment: Because we can't use `match_parent` in a `ConstraintLayout`. We can only use the constraints and these values for the `layout_width` or `layout_height` properties of the contents of a `ConstraintLayout`: `0dp` (`match_constraint`), `wrap_content` or a custom value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of I set the `layoutDirection` of the `AppCompatEditText` to `rtl`. As it should be Right-to-Left, I didn't set it to `ltr`, but I changed its constraints from

```
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/clearBtnLyt"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar1"
```

to

```
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/clearBtnLyt"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar1"
```

Note that I changed `End` to `Right` and `Start` to `Left`, e.g. `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf` to `app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bug, It has confusion between start/end and left/right when you change layoutDirection RTL,
You can change start to left and right to en, same:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/clearBtnLyt"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar1" />
```